# image map alternative (maybe in javascript?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, imagemap

Alright, so I was wondering if there was an alternative, lightweight way to creating an image map.

Basically, I want to take this image:

[image]

And have the sections of the diagram light up when they are hovered over, kinda like this (I've mocked it up in photoshop):

[image]

The other sections (which I haven't named yet) should be able to do the same. Also, I'd like to be able to use javascript later to have sliding links appear from behind those sections (I roughly know how to do that now, so I'm okay that)

Does anyone have any suggestions? Just a general direction on what to search for would be great.

Comment: Oh my. I'm pretty sure that could be achieved with pure CSS. A bit difficult but it's a nice challenge ;)

Comment: Yep! I know I could just do a rollover, but I'd love if there's a way I could do it without having to load six different images. I just started using javascript, so I'm trying to cut corners in as many places as I can to keep file sizes down ;)

Comment: @ Arkana: Alright, I've played around with this a bit, and I thought maybe I could put a full coloured image as the background, and then have those three circles overlaying the image at half opacity. Then when you put your mouse over it, voila, opacity is set to 0, and the image (or part of it anyway) appears! HOWEVER! If there were a way to make two of the circles disappear at the same time to account for the overlapping areas, that would solve my problem. And then I'll just stick an image in the middle for the white part. Any suggestions? And thanks for your help so far. I've learnt alot.

Answer (score 3):

Map tag would be good and it is not actually heavyweight as it does not require any external plug-ins.
However, since you just want a general idea: Once due to some error, I wasn't able to use map tag. So I split the original image into different images (positioned them as the original image was) and then used events on separate parts.
Tiresome, but a workaround.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how I'd piece together something that complicated though XD I might give it a try if nothing else works :)

Answer (score 2):

Circles are easy to do with CSS. You can start with something like this :

```
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-border-radius: 70px;
-webkit-border-radius: 70px;
border-radius: 70px;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CgLvP/)**

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks - it's not exactly the solution I'm looking for, but I had no idea you could do that. I'll see if I can't play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult for me to achieve that white shape in the middle, but here's a simple try:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8zTz/

Only with three `div` and a few css:

HTML

```
<div class="rojo"></div>
<div class="azul"></div>
<div class="amar"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:100px; position:absolute; opacity:0.5;}
.rojo {background:red; top:0; left:30px;}
.azul {background:cornflowerblue; top:60px; left:0;}
.amar {background:gold; top:60px; left:70px;}
div:hover {opacity:1; z-index:-1}
```

(Z-index is for stack the div behind the other and reach transparency).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wow - what an elegant way to do it! I just gotta figure out how to get the intersections highlighted, and then maybe I can just stick an image in the middle to get the white part. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that the tricky point! The "inner" shapes, both the white one and the intersections as you say. Have you see the [Chrome logo](http://cssnerd.nl/articles/pure_css_chrome_logo.html) with CSS? I think it could help too.

Comment: Interesting. In Firefox (27.0.1), at least, it shows a weakness and/or ambiguity for "hover": moving within the intersections, it flickers as which div gets opacity 1 alternates. (In the 3-way intersection, it flickers between just 2 of the three.)

Answer (score 0):

Take two images
1)normal image
2)the particular section higligthed when hovered image

```
<img id="originalimage" src="originalimage.png" width="140" height="140" border="0" usemap="#Map" />   

<map name="Map" id="Map">      
  <area shape="rect" coords="77,18,127,90" href="#" onmouseover="onHover('higlightedimageonhover-imagesrc.png')" onmouseout="onout6('originalimagesrc.png')"/>

</map>



<script>


function onHover6(image1)
{
document.getElementById('originalimage').src=image1;
} 
function onout6(image2)
{ 
document.getElementById('originalimage').src=image2; 
} 
</script>
```

Here when you `hover` on the co-ordinates, the image changes to hoverimages and `on mouseout` it changes to original image.